# Installing package with fixed version in Brew

Tags: homebrew

What's the way of installing a package with fixed version in brew? I would run something like the following command, but my tryings didn't work.

```
brew install package -v 1.2.3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: Is there only one formula for each package? So you can't fix the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

Will install version 5.7 of MySQL rather that the latest version.